# Lua global variable containing path to current file?

Tags: module, lua, filesystems, filenames, interpreter

Is there a global variable in Lua that contains the path to the file currently being interpreted? Something like Python's `__file__` variable?

I ran a quick `for k, v in pairs(_G) do print(k) end` in the interpreter to see if I could find anything. Only the following variables were listed?

`string xpcall package tostring print os unpack require getfenv setmetatable next assert tonumber io rawequal collectgarbage getmetatable module rawset math debug pcall table newproxy type coroutine _G select gcinfo pairs rawget loadstring ipairs _VERSION dofile setfenv load error loadfile`

Any suggestions on how to get the path the file currently being executed?

Comment: That will return the filename that Lua was launched with, however, it will not return the "current file", which will change with the `require` command.

Comment: Just a note that the `arg` table is only available when running a script via the `lua` command-line interpreter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The debug library has a `getinfo` method you can call, which can return, amongst other things, the source file for a function.

```
local info = debug.getinfo(1,'S');
print(info.source);
```

That would return the name of the source file (which will begin with an @ symbol, indicating it is a filename) of the function at the first level of the call stack. By passing `1` you are asking for information about the current function. If you passed in `0` it would return `=[C]` as it would be returning information about the `getinfo` function itself.

For more detailed information check out the `Programming in Lua` reference on the official Lua website:
http://www.lua.org/pil/23.1.html

Comment: This totally works but assumes two things: 1) the `debug` library is available in the build of Lua it is running on. 2) the code that is running has not been pre-compiled with debug info stripped (e.g., with `luac -s`). Neither of these things is always under the control of the script author.

Comment: +1 for very valid points I should of pointed out in my original answer. Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: Also note that functions such as `loadstring` can set the value to arbitrary strings.

Comment: That is why I did mention that filenames would begin with `@`, otherwise if using `loadstring` then source would actually contain the source passed to `loadstring`.

Comment: You can pass the chunk name as a second parameter to loadstring. Ex: `loadstring("foo()", "@/this/file/doesnt/exist")`. This is how `require` sets the source file.

Answer (score 7):

In Lua 5.2, when a script is loaded via `require`, it receives as arguments the module name given to `require` and the filename that `require` used to open the script:

```
$ cat a.lua
require"b"
$ cat b.lua
print("in b",...)
$ lua a.lua
in b    b   ./b.lua
```

In Lua 5.1, only the module name is passed, not the filename.

Answer (score 7):

In response to the answer by [lhf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21419777/2434169):
Being new to Lua, I was initially confused what `...` meant. Turns out it's a vararg just like with ANSI C: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4. In my experience with lua 5.3, using

```
local packageName, packagePath = ...
```

got me the package name as when used in a require and the absolute file path of the package.