# Find name and location of Lua executeable

Tags: lua

I need to find the name of the Lua executeable from within a Lua script as it sets up a task for later execution.

Using `arg` I can find out the name, however this becomes un reliable if options are used. For example, if no arguments are used running within a script `print( arg[-1])` would print `lua53`. However if options are used they would be printed instead, such as `-i`, and to get the exe I would have change the line to `print( arg[-2])`.

What method will reliably get the name of the lua binary?

Comment: This question can help [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21416798/lua-global-variable-containing-path-to-current-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
i=0
repeat i=i-1 until arg[i]==nil
i=i+1
print(i,arg[i])
```