# Lua referencing a file from a folder in the parent directory

Tags: lua, love2d

Using Love2d, I would like to load in an image that is located in a folder found in the parent directory.

```
Project
> code
>> main.lua
> resources
>> placeholderImage.jpg
```

What is the proper way to reference the parent directory?

```
function love.load()
  image = love.graphics.newImage("../resources/placeholderImage.jpg");
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It cannot be done: In love2d, you can only load images from your game directory, the one containing your `main.lua`.

Try adding a symbolic link in your game directory:

```
ln -s ../resources .
```

and then use `love.graphics.newImage("resources/placeholderImage.jpg")`.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm writing this under the Ubuntu 18.04 operating system. I'll probably just rearrange my files for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: Thinking about it again, the way I had my files set up would have made converting the game into an executable impossible. I should have had main.lua in my top directory to begin with.

Comment: Technically I think you can load files from the game's save directory too, and the program directory or a zip file in the save directory using [mount](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.filesystem.mount) if the game is fused to the Love executable.  So you could have a mods directory in the directory your program is in, or in the directory where games are saved and load images from there.

Answer (score 0):

The `..` you're using now is relative to the working directory of the program, which may not be the same as the directory containing the code.  One way to do what you want is to first determine the path to the code, which can be achieved using `debug.getinfo()` as described here: [Lua global variable containing path to current file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21416798/lua-global-variable-containing-path-to-current-file)

Comment: running `print(debug.getinfo(1,'S').source)` outputs "@main.lua" and moving up one level gives me "boot.lua". I'm a bit confused on how I use the information from debug.getinfo() to generate a file path.